# getting "IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied" when running "numpy.f2py.compile()"

Tags: python, numpy, compilation, f2py, ioerror

googled many similar keywords. No help.

copied example from: 
https://numpy.org/devdocs/f2py/usage.html into IDE (pyscripter)
ran python2.7
received an error msg (see below):

```
*** Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov  8 2017, 13:40:13) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32. ***
>>> 
*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized  ***
>>> 
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "hello" sources
f2py options: []
f2py:> c:\users\kalma\appdata\local\temp\tmpqgzjp1\src.win32-2.7\hellomodule.c
creating c:\users\kalma\appdata\local\temp\tmpqgzjp1\src.win32-2.7
Reading fortran codes...
Post-processing...
Post-processing (stage 2)...
Building modules...
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\users\\kalma\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmptmlgrm.f'. Skipping file "c:\users\kalma\appdata\local\temp\tmptmlgrm.f".
error: f2py target file 'c:\\users\\kalma\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpqgzjp1\\src.win32-2.7\\hellomodule.c' not generated
>>>
```

QUESTION: where do I go from here to find an answer

Comment: Can you run your IDE in administrator mode?

Comment: Yes, I did. NO difference.